# Add decimal mark to each number of each line

Tags: regular-expression

I have an R file of results, such as below:

```
filename run1 run2 run3
file1.py 109 103 100
file2.py 14123 14323 14333  
...
filen.py 2007 2130 2001
```

What is the easiest way to use VIM for adding decimal mark three places (from back, div 1000) to each number in each line?

Something like

```
filename run1 run2 run3
file1.py 0.109 0.103 0.100
file2.py 14.123 14.323 14.333  
...
filen.py 2.007 2.130 2.001
```

As @BLayer commented:
Updated the example to make it more clear. For example numbers 1 and 10 should remain the same but three digit numbers like 100 should become  0.100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here's the simplest way of doing it from my point of view:

```
:%s/\d\{3}\>/.&/g
```

#### Explanation

- `%s` is here to search and replace

---

- `\d\{3}` represents 3 digits
- `\>` represents the end of a word (here the end of the number)

---

- `.` is a dot
- `&` repeats what you matched

---

As [@BLayer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/11054/b-layer) noted, this solution can create numbers starting with a dot (e.g. "`.123`").
If That's not something you want, you can:

- Exclude the 3 digits numbers from the search:

```
:%s/\d\zs\d\{3}\>/.&/g
```

- Add a leading 0:

```
:%s/\D\zs\d\{3}\>/0.&/g
:%s/\d\zs\d\{3}\>/.&/g
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add dots on every number and then move it forward. This is cool.

Comment: Doesn't this lead to 3 digit numbers like `100` becoming `.100`? If that's not what you want then a pattern like `\d\zs\d\{3}\>` might be better. Or maybe you want that or you won't ever have 3-digit numbers...question isn't totally clear on that point.

Comment: Yes. This is a possibility. And @zorzi has updated his answer. Thanks again.